# Mongoose: set single option in Model.remove()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-models

[Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#remove_remove)  says about `Model::remove()` method:

> Removes all documents that match conditions from the collection. To
>   remove just the first document that matches conditions, **set the single
>   option to true**.

The question is how to set this option?

I've tried:

1) `Model.remove({code: 55, single: true }, function (err, deleted) {...` — no result, because, as I can expect, `single` in this case is considered as a field, which doesn't exist;

2) `Model.remove({code: 55},  {single: true }, function (err, deleted) {` — `TypeError: callback.apply is not a function`.

I'm a Mongoose-beginner, thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Note that using the static `remove` doesn't trigger your schema's middleware, i.e. pre('save'...), validate, etc. Are you sure you don't want to find and remove instead? http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: Yes, I've read about it and I undestand, that `deleteOne()` is preferred. I just want to know, how to set that this `single` option, if it's possible.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, when I run `Model.remove({code: 55}, null, {single: true }, function (err, deleted) {...`, callback even does not trigger...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my, I've found, how to solve it - [in source code](https://github.com/zbjornson/mongoose/commit/ceb8d38866c26ffd57159b4b1f32f9c67dad37dd):

`Model.remove({code: 55}).setOptions({ single: true }).exec(function (err, deleted) {...`